# Customizing decimal mark used in plot frame tick labels

Tags: plotting, number-representation, localization, labeling

I am using the `Plot` function in a usual way. I use Mathematica 9.0.1.0 in English (I do not know if it is available in other languages, but I do not mind), and as a result of that, the numbers that appear in the frame tick labels use *dots* as decimal markers.

I need all numbers in the plot to be shown with a *comma* as a decimal marker. Is that possible?

Here you have a MWE —nothing special:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> 600, 
 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 12]]
```

This is what I get:

[image: Minimum Working Example]

This is a minor issue, as I can export the image and change its labels outside Mathematica, but in case I would like to do this inside Mathematica, how could I get it?

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

I've tried it by using `$Language = "Spanish"`, with no success.

Comment: `LabelStyle -> 
 Directive[FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 12, 
  NumberPoint -> ","]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use the option `NumberPoint->","` as a sub-option in `LabelStyle`:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
    Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> 600, 
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 20, Red, NumberPoint -> ","]]
```

[image]

Or use `BaseStyle -> (NumberPoint -> ",")`:

```
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
    Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> 600, 
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
    BaseStyle -> (NumberPoint -> ","),
    LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 20, Red]]

 (* same picture *)
```

Comment: I just found the same solution at the same time! Thank you!

Comment: @Vicent, "Great minds ..." / _Mr.Wizard_  :) Welcome to MMMSE.

Answer (score 4):

First, you can use `Style`:

```
Style[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
  Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> 600, 
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 12]],
 NumberPoint -> ","]
```

[image]

Second, you can set it globally in Preferences > Appearance > Numbers > Formatting.

Third, you can select the output cell and use the Options Inspector to set the `NumberPoint` option for the cell.

Comment: OK! Thanks! In fact, I have just found the answer at the same time. This is an alternative, putting `NumberPoint` within the `LabelStyle`option:  `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> 600, 
 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
 LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[FontFamily -> "Calibri", FontSize -> 12, 
   NumberPoint -> ","]]`

Comment: @Vincent Cool.  I didn't try `LabelStyle`.  You can put that in your own answer.  Some other users might look only at the answers and not at the comments.

Comment: Another user gave the same answer than me. If you don't mind, I am going to give him the "mark".

Comment: @Vicent  No problem.  Actually, it's good practice to wait (at least a few hours) before accepting.  You encourage more answers that way, and sometimes the best one is not the first one.

Comment: I'm including this to `BaseStyle` :)

Answer (score 2):

To apply the comma to several plots, resp. to any output:

```
$Post = Style[#, NumberPoint -> ","] &

Grid[{Plot[#@x, {x, 0, Pi}] & /@ {Cos, Sin, Tanh}}]
```

[image]

```
$Post=. (* Reset *)
```

You can customize the `NumberPoint` also via `Option Inspector` (Menu "Format")

Comment: Wow, thank you!